# Adding extra axis in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I have a ggplot like below with a dataframe called df that looks like this:

```
         prob             x_val
1        0.1              0.20
2        0.12             0.21
3        0.3              0.22
4        0.001            0.23
5        0.0001           0.24
6        0.00001          0.25
```

and ggplot plotted like this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=x_val, y=prob))
```

I would like to make the prob values log scaled and plot them in the same ggplot but have an extra log scaled y axis on the right.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77706058/adding-extra-axis-in-ggplot help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stroke` and `shape` are not valid arguments to `geom_line`. Perhaps you are looking for `linewidth` and `linetype`?

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(escape_prob, aes(x_val, prob)) +
  geom_textline(aes(label = "normal scale"), vjust = -0.2, color = "red3",
                size = 6) +
  geom_textline(aes(label = "log scale", y = 0.1 * log10(prob) + 0.5),
                size = 6,
                color = "#427D9D", linetype = 3, linewidth = 1, vjust = -0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(10^((.x - 0.5)*10)), 
                                         breaks = 10^seq(-6, 0),
                                         labels = scales::number_format()),
                labels = scales::number_format()) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for posting this. The issue is not really shape and stroke, I copy pasted some of my code and changed it so it looks simpler. I want two plots, one the actual line, and the log scaled line overlapped onto one plot with the log scale axis on the right. This is only showing one plot.

Comment: @A4747 that's unusual, but OK, see my update.

Comment: Almost perfect. Just one minor suggestion: 'steelblue3' pairs better with 'red3', while '#427D9D' seems to complement 'tomato3' more effectively, in my humble opinion. :-)